# Why don't buttons work in AlertDialog in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a dialog box which code looks like this:

```dart
//Alert Dialog about questions and answers
  void _showAlertDialog() {

    // set up the buttons
    Widget Answer1Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      onPressed:  () {
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][2];
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][6];
        print(_listData[_listCount][2]);
        _nextCSV();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );
    Widget Answer2Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][5]),
      onPressed:  () {
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][4];
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][7];
        print(_listCount);
        print(assetPath);
        print(_listData[_listCount][4]);
        _nextCSV();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text(_listData[_listCount][1]),
      actions: [
        Answer1Button,
        Answer2Button,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,  //use to dismiss any tap on the background of the dialog
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return true;   // false to disable the back button
          },
          child: alert,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

But when I click on those buttons, nothing happens. As an example, I added a lot of things there. But even when there is only one function, it is not executed. If there is a print command, then it is not in the console either.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edi1.** This is a full code:

```dart
// New Game route
class NewGameRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'New Game',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  String assetPath = "files/main.jpg";
  // bool shouldPop = true;  Maybe useful in the future

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    // assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == ""
    //     ? "files/main.jpg"
    //     : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      // assetPath =
      // _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
    });
  }

  // This function makes buttons visible/invisible
  bool isVisible = true; //will be visible for the first frame

  void _isVisible() {
    setState(() {
      isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
  }


  //Alert Dialog about questions and answers
  void _showAlertDialog() {

    // set up the buttons
    Widget Answer1Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      // onPressed:  () {
      //   _listCount = _listData[_listCount][2];
      //   assetPath = _listData[_listCount][6];
      //   print(_listData[_listCount][2]);
      //   _nextCSV();
      //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
      // },
      // onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
      // onPressed:  () {
      //   Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
      // },
        onPressed: _nextCSV



    );
    Widget Answer2Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][5]),
      // onPressed:  () {
      //   _listCount = _listData[_listCount][4];
      //   assetPath = _listData[_listCount][7];
      //   print(_listCount);
      //   print(assetPath);
      //   print(_listData[_listCount][4]);
      //   _nextCSV();
      //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
      // },
      // onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
      // onPressed:  () {
      //   Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
      // },
        onPressed: _nextCSV


    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text(_listData[_listCount][1]),
      actions: [
        Answer1Button,
        Answer2Button,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,  //use to dismiss any tap on the background of the dialog
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return true;   // false to disable the back button
          },
          child: alert,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New Game'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Test1', onButtonTap: _showAlertDialog),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                visible: isVisible,
              ),
              // your other widgets
              Visibility(
                child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                visible: !isVisible,
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: That would be good if you share some snippet of code that how you are using this function.

Comment: I have added the complete code in Edit1. I hope this helps you find the problem faster. My guess is that onPressed doesn't work on this dialog because it's being used as a method. I'm sorry if I get confused in terminology. I am a newbie. But even I see that in other examples everything works. But the problem is that I need the code of my dialog box to be separately for a better understanding of the code.

Comment: try to add `await` before `showDialog(barrierDismissible: false, ... ` and make you `_showAlertDialog` Future. Not sure what you mean exactly by "_need the code of my dialog box to be separately for a better understanding of the code._"

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Although during testing I managed to find something. In particular, pressing my buttons works. So the problem is in those lines that are inside. But I will need time to establish at what stage the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to seperate your textButtons with functions not setting a variable.

```
  Widget _answer1TextButton(){
         return TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      onPressed:  () {
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][2];
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][6];
        print(_listData[_listCount][2]);
        _nextCSV();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _answer2TextButton(){
         return TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][5]),
      onPressed:  () {
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][4];
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][7];
        print(_listCount);
        print(assetPath);
        print(_listData[_listCount][4]);
        _nextCSV();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );
  }

  void _showAlertDialog() {


// set up the AlertDialog
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  // title: Text(),
  content: Text(_listData[_listCount][1]),
  actions: [
    _answer1TextButton(),
    _answer2TextButton(),
  ],
);

// show the dialog
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,  //use to dismiss any tap on the background of the dialog
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return true;   // false to disable the back button
      },
      child: alert,
    );
  },
);


}
```

Comment: Perhaps this looks better. But the problem remains. Nothing happens when these buttons are pressed. Even printing in the console. Why?

Comment: @Texter if you are getting the print result on the console when pressed the button, then the buttons are working fine, you need to check the functions in onpressed parameter

Comment: @Texter you can comment the lines in onpressed by one by until you figure out where is the problem. for example if _nextCSV() returns a error then Navigator.of(context).pop(); will not work

Comment: Yes, if I add print('Answer 1');, then I see Answer 1. But everything else does not work, which is strange. Since the text for questions and answers is taken from the same file. And there are no problems... I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of the `AlertDialogBox` class That I use. You can tweak the list body in a way you want to show (for example, changing the number of buttons, etc.).

```
class AlertDialogBox {
  AlertDialogBox({
    required this.alertTitle,
    required this.alertText,
    required this.buttonLeftText,
    required this.buttonRightText,
    required this.buttonRightAction,
  });
  final Widget alertTitle;
  final String alertText;
  final String buttonLeftText;
  final String buttonRightText;
  final VoidCallback buttonRightAction;

  Future<void> yesAbortDialog(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Platform.isIOS
            ? CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: alertTitle,
                // contentTextStyle: kAlertTextStyle,
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Text(alertText, style: kAlertTextStyle),
                      Text(alertText),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text(buttonLeftText),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: buttonRightAction,
                    child: Text(buttonRightText),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : AlertDialog(
                title: alertTitle,
                // contentTextStyle: kAlertTextStyle,
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Text(alertText, style: kAlertTextStyle),
                      Text(alertText),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text(buttonLeftText),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: buttonRightAction,
                    child: Text(buttonRightText),
                  ),
                ],
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use it in this way:

```
onPressed:  () {
        AlertDialogBox(
          alertTitle: '',
          buttonRightAction: ()  {},
          alertText:
          '',
          buttonLeftText: '',
          buttonRightText: '',
        ).yesAbortDialog(context);
      },
```

I have set the left button to pop the dialogue, but you can implement what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good alternative to what I have now. However, my problem lies in the functions and methods themselves. So it will take me a while to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I suggest to refactore your code using this sample and if it is not still working, comment here and eddit your question with a MRE that others can run (not using specific variables like `String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);` )

Comment: Oh, thanks. This is a great idea. I have never done that so far. So it will be a rewarding experience for me.